# SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer doesn't works

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, t-sql

Sorry for asking, but I haven't solved my question by reading another situation like I have.

I have an array with longs and I should insert it into a database, that has only 2 fields: `OGRN - bigint`, data field, `Id - int`, identity field. I'm creating a DataTable like this

```
        private static DataTable CreateDataTable()
    {
        var result = new DataTable();

        var ogrn = new DataColumn("Ogrn") {DataType = typeof (long), ColumnName = "Ogrn"};
        result.Columns.Add(ogrn);

        var id = new DataColumn("Id") { DataType = typeof(int), ColumnName = "Id", AutoIncrement = true };
        result.Columns.Add(id);
        result.PrimaryKey = new[] { id };
        return result;
    }
```

after i'm doing this:

```
            var dt = CreateDataTable();
            foreach (long ogrn in ogrns)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();
                row["Ogrn"] = ogrn;
                dt.AcceptChanges();
            }
            using (var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.ULs";
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Ogrn", "Ogrn");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "Id");
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
```

So why doesn't it work? Am I missing something important.

Comment: Define in much greater detail what you mean by `doesn't works`.

Comment: Give your table script. Is ID field is autoincremented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Add the new row to the Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)!. That is not something that is automagically done when you call `NewRow();`

```
            var dt = CreateDataTable();
            foreach (long ogrn in ogrns)
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();
                row["Ogrn"] = ogrn.Ogrn;
                dt.Rows.Add(row); // ADD the new row to the table!
            }
            dt.AcceptChanges();
```